# Logging / Printing from a pymongo Map Reduce Operation

Tags: python, debugging, mongodb, logging, pymongo

The mongo shell includes a useful `print` command.

When executing [`map_reduce`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.map_reduce) from pymongo, how can one print / log info from within a javascript block?

**Update:** OK, I have an answer.  The process running `mongo` will output whatever is printed with `print()`.  A second option is to configure [mongo logging](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Logging) (and probably tailing the log files).  Virtual bonus points for answering "Can I still get these values directly in python via pymongo?"

Comment: Possibly look at `console.log()` from inside your javascript.

Comment: Nope: `map invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: console is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `print()` inside the JS block which will get written to `/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`, [more info here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Troubleshooting+MapReduce).  Due to the fact that `map/reduce` happens server-side it won't emit anything in your Python application.